# passing geocode results object to another file

Tags: javascript, geocoding, leaflet, jquery

I'm using a geocoding plugin ([Leafet.GeoSearch](https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch)) on a map and I'd like the results, being the LatLng point coordinates, etc available as a parameter for GeoServer cql filtered calls.

It doesn't seem to be as easy as I thought it would be. I've read several forums which claim data can't be persistent between pages/files. Could someone enlighten me and or make a suggestion please. I'm in over my head.

here is a snippet of the code that has the array I'd like available

```
ParseJSON : function(data) {
        if (data.resourceSets.length == 0 || data.resourceSets[0].resources.length == 0)
            return [];

        var results = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.resourceSets[0].resources.length; i++)
            results.push(new L.GeoSearch.Result(
                data.resourceSets[0].resources[i].point.coordinates[1], 
                data.resourceSets[0].resources[i].point.coordinates[0], 
                data.resourceSets[0].resources[i].address.formattedAddress));
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: sorry about the title but I'm a javascript newb. I was hoping this would be an easy answer, but as I continue research there seems to be some disparity among suggested methods. All of which I haven't a clue how to implement. hopefully someone with experience will have an idea what I want and edit this question.

Comment: Are you asking to get the data out of the function and use it somewhere else on the page? In which case @geomajor56's answer works. If you want to use it in another page, or use it in a different program that is going to be very tricky as JavaScript sandboxes all of the web pages to prevent this, depending on what exactly your trying to do you're most likely going to want to get the data closer to where you're going to use it.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Also, OP answered his own question so it's probably best to delete this.

Answer (score 1):

Got a solution from Boston Python Users Group IRC.

"all global variables are implicitly attached to the `window` object — if you attach a variable to the `window` object, you'll be able to access it from anywhere". example window.myArray = the_object

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.resourceSets[0].resources.length; i++)
        results.push(new L.GeoSearch.Result(
            data.resourceSets[0].resources[i].point.coordinates[1], 
            data.resourceSets[0].resources[i].point.coordinates[0], 
            data.resourceSets[0].resources[i].address.formattedAddress));
            ***window.thisAddress = results;*** // this is all I needed       
    return results;
```